# Execute function/method of an object

Tags: javascript, function, object

Is there a way to get something like this to work in JS:

```
function iterateObject(obj, f) {
    for (let prop in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) f(prop);
    }
}
```

And then apply it on an object:

```
let x = {a : function() {
    // do smth
}};

iterateObject(x, (prop) => {
    prop.a();
}
```

I'm getting an error that prop.a() is not a function but if I call x.a() there is no problem. Not super important but I'm just wondering and couldn't find an answer.

Comment: Well yes, you should just use `x.a()`. What's your actual problem?

Comment: Try with `f(obj[prop])` and `val => val()` as callback, or `x[prop]()` in the callback

Comment: the string of the property name is being passed to your `f` so what's happening is really `'a'.a();` not `x['a']();`

Comment: Why do you want to use an `iterateObject(x, (prop) =>` function with callback when you could simply use a `for (let prop in x)` loop?

Comment: To iterate over numerous nested objects and call the same method for each but have numerous such nested objects with different methods to call so this reduces code.

Comment: Ah, the iteration method you posted doesn't yet consider nested objects. In that case, you should go with Anurag's answer instead of Tom's

Comment: @Bergi I'll try that too thanks, atm Tom's answer is working for my case though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your invocation of `iterateObject`, inside the anonymous function, `prop` is the string `"a"`. Also, `x` is your original object.

To access a property by name (`prop`) on an object (`x`), you would have to do `x[prop]`. To invoke that function, you should write `x[prop]()` inside your anonymous function.

Comment: Thanks that is the answer, I was kinda not aware that prop is just the key.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function iterateObject(obj, f) {
  for (let prop in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      f(obj[prop]); 
      // You were earlier just passing the key 'a' as a string to the function.
      // Hence it was giving you an error
      // You need to pass the function i.e obj[prop]
    }
  }
}

let x = {
  a: function() {
    console.log('hello');
  }
};

iterateObject(x, (prop) => {
  // You will get the function as prop
  // To execute it you need to directly call it using prop()
  prop();
});
```